# How to check windon next url when click on any tag link a, button or submit button?

Tags: javascript, url, browser

Like I have website with internal web site page link and social media and other website link, If User click any link, div which has onclick event, button any type of event which is reload page or go in other page in site.

I want to check that user is leaving website or just go into another page of website.

Simple, I want to check that user is on my web page and leave before reload page or browser url change to next url.